# Kubernetes: print namespace in helm status output

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In the output of *helm status mychart*, it show **NAMESPACE** in which chart is deployed that is **NAMESPACE: default**.

```
#=> helm status mychart
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Sep 24 21:32:45 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED
==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                     READY  STATUS   RESTARTS  AGE
nginx-web-stg-55f55958-v2cxm             0/1    Pending  0         28m
tomcat-api-stg-6d54498fdd-cqctr          1/1    Running  0         28m
```

and if I run *kubectl get all -A*, It show **NAMESPACE** along with resouces name-

```
#=> kubectl get all -A
NAMESPACE           NAME                             READY    STATUS  RESTARTS  AGE
nginx         pod/nginx-web-stg-55f55958-v2cxm        0/1     Pending    0      20m
tomcat        pod/tomcat-api-stg-6d54498fdd-cqctr     1/1     Running    0      20m
```

In the Kubectl output, column for **NAMESPACE** is included in output but not in *helm status mychart*. I wish to print resources along with **NAMESPACE** in *helm status mychart* output.

Answer (score 1):

The output formats of `kubectl` and `helm` are completely unrelated. I'm not aware that you can modify the output of `helm status` in any way to make it display the namespace with each resource.

Comment: I agree ```helm status``` do not provide to customise/modify its output format. But with this format, it will be hard to differntiate the resources inside cluster with multiple namespaces. 

The other option is to use ```kubectl``` to filter with specifying namespace and one bad thing is ```kubectl get all -A``` does not provide all resources list which makes more comples.

Comment: `kubectl get all` [does not display all resources](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151), but you can add more resource types by using, for example, `kubectl get all,secrets,nodes -A`. That's probably the closest you can get to list all resources you want in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

**Helm** helps you manage Kubernetes applications — Helm Charts help you define, install, and upgrade even the most complex Kubernetes application.

The Kubernetes command-line tool, **kubectl**, allows you to run commands against Kubernetes clusters. You can use kubectl to deploy applications, inspect and manage cluster resources, and view logs.

According to [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151) simply execute:

$  kubectl api-resources  -o name   | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l release=your-chart-name --all-namespaces

Sample output:

```
user@home:~$ kubectl api-resources  -o name   | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l release=terrific-ferret --all-namespaces

NAME                                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
componentstatus/scheduler            Healthy   ok
componentstatus/etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}
componentstatus/etcd-1               Healthy   {"health": "true"}
componentstatus/controller-manager   Healthy   ok
NAMESPACE   NAME                                   DATA   AGE
default     configmap/terrific-ferret-mysql-test   1      12m
NAMESPACE   NAME                              ENDPOINTS          AGE
default     endpoints/terrific-ferret-mysql   aa.bb.cc.dd:port   12m
NAMESPACE   NAME                                          STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
default     persistentvolumeclaim/terrific-ferret-mysql   Bound    pvc-896382d2   8Gi        RWO            standard       12m
NAMESPACE   NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default     pod/terrific-ferret-mysql-86588b4646   1/1     Running   0          2m55s
NAMESPACE   NAME                           TYPE     DATA   AGE
default     secret/terrific-ferret-mysql   Opaque   2      13m
NAMESPACE   NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
default     service/terrific-ferret-mysql   ClusterIP   xx.yy.zz.ww   <none>        3306/TCP   13m
NAMESPACE   NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default     deployment.apps/terrific-ferret-mysql   1         1         1            1           13m
NAMESPACE   NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
default     replicaset.apps/terrific-ferret-mysql-86  1         1         1       13m
```

We are using **kubectl api-resources** to list all supported resource types along with their shortnames.

Useful information you can find here: [api-resources](http://matthieure.me/2019/06/18/kubernetes-api-resources.html).

Useful blog: [kubectlcheatsheet](https://medium.com/faun/kubectl-commands-cheatsheet-43ce8f13adfb).

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you check it ? Please let me know if its work.